# How to Source a File and Pass Inputs to Sourced File in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app like below.  When I press the `Execute` button I would like to `source(test.R)`.  That works fine below.  However, I'd like `test.R` to take `input$id` as an input, and execute based on it.  How can I do that?  I tried the below, and it doesn't work.

Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Test App'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(
        inputId = 'customer_id',
        label = 'Type an ID',
        value = 'G123'
      ),
      actionButton(
        inputId = 'run',
        label = 'Execute'
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput('display')
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$display <- renderText({'Test Text'})
  
  observeEvent(input$run, {
    source("test.R")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Test.R:

```
val <-
  reactive({
    print(input$customer_id)
  })
```

Comment: You should instead try to move the logic of the script to a function on click. I don't think you can run `reactive` code in a script.

Comment: @RonakShah, I'm not sure I follow.  I can change test.R to contain a function and call that function from the server side in shiny, but that still doesn't work.  `fn_print_value <- function(value){
  print(value)
}`

Comment: If you write the script as a function which it looks like you've done, you can always `source("test.R")` in the [global.R](https://mraess.rbind.io/2018/07/the-awesomeness-that-is-the-global-r-file-or-how-to-clean-up-your-shiny-app/) script or above your `app.R`. That way you don't have to load the function in several times. Then you would just call the name of the function inside your observeEvent. However, I agree with @RonakShah on the not having the reactive inside this function though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created two files `app.R` and `test.R` in the same working directory.

*`app.R`*

```
library(shiny)

source("test.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Test App'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(inputId = 'customer_id',label = 'Type an ID',value = 'G123'),
      actionButton(inputId = 'run',label = 'Execute')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput('display')
    )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$display <- renderText({'Test Text'})
  
  observeEvent(input$run, {
    my_fun(input$customer_id)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

*`test.R`*

```
my_fun <- function(input_value) {
  print(input_value)
}
```

and when you run `app.R` and hit `Execute!` you see the customer id printed in the console.